# "Простите(,) за все эти фразы". Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Простите, за все эти фразы.

Мне кажется, запятая тут лишняя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом месте *возможен* знак препинания для отделения уточняющего оборота от самодостаточного извинения "простите". Тире может добавить извинению спонтанности, эмоциональности - в письменной форме; многоточие уместно при передаче длительной паузы в устной речи (речи персонажа), если уточнение произнесено "вдогонку". Запятая для таких целей не подходит, и нейтральный вариант должен быть без знака препинания.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, лишняя. Простите — это глагол в повелительном наклонении. От него зависит существительное: простите (за что?) за фразы. Условий для запятой нет.

Answer (score 1):

**Простите за все эти фразы.**

Стандартное сочетание, которое произносится без паузы, так как глагол управляет дополнением: **простите (за что?) за все эти фразы.**

А если нет паузы, **то нет и запятой**.

Ситуация, когда в эмоциональной речи персонажа присутствует пауза, в принципе возможна, но тогда паузу лучше обозначить многоточием, например: **Простите... за все эти фразы, за всё.**

Answer (score 0):

Судя по метке, вы считаете "простите" вводным словом. На деле это член предложения (насколько я знаю, такие глаголы в повелительном наклонении считаются сказуемыми).